# Reminder Command issue

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

I'm having a problem on my reminder command. When the reminder command is running, it works properly: It will remind you in the seconds you provided. But when it's running the reminder, it will not run any other command until it has DM to remind you.

Here is the code. I'm not really good at explaining; you can just ask questions.

```
@client.command()
async def remindersec(ctx,seconds=None):
  try:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"I will remind you in {seconds} seconds",
    description = f"You'll be DMed as a reminder.",
    color = 0xf461ff)

    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    timer = int(seconds)
    while timer >= 0:
      import time
      time.sleep(1)
      timer -= 1
    await ctx.author.send("Reminder!")
  except ValueError:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Error!",
    description = f"Please type a valid number.",
    color = 0xf461ff)

    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  except TypeError:
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Error!",
    description = f"Please type a valid number.",
    color = 0xf461ff)

    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

    embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by  {ctx.author} at {current_time}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: `time.sleep` freezes the whole process, so i don't recommend you use `time.sleep`

Comment: Also, why are you importing the `time` module at the function? You should put it on top of your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use time module. Use asyncio. So it would be like :-

```
import asyncio

timer = int(seconds)
while timer >= 0:
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  timer -= 1
  await ctx.author.send("Reminder!")
except ValueError:
  embed = discord.Embed(title = "Error!",
  description = f"Please type a valid number.",
  color = 0xf461ff)
```

Comment: asyncio.sleep is a coroutine, it needs to be awaited, otherwise it won’t do anything

Comment: instead of the while loop you should just be able to use `asyncio.sleep(timer)`. if you still wanna use it the `ctx.author.send` should probably not be in the loop though lol